# Unable to get the values from another class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask which is inside a class. The outer class contains a variable which will be updated after running AsyncTask. However, when I access the outer class's variable from MainActivity, it shows null value.

MainActivity class:

```
RetrieveJSON retrieve = new RetrieveJSON();
                retrieve.new RetrieveWarehouseSalesJSON(MainActivity.this).execute();
                String location = retrieve.sales_location;
                System.out.println("Location is: " + location);
```

Location shows null value.

RetrieveJSON class (which contains AsyncTask):

```
public class RetrieveJSON {
    String sales_location;
   class RetrieveWarehouseSalesJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
      //....
   sales_location = s.getString("title");
                            System.out.println("Sales_locatiion" + sales_location);
   }
}
```

sales_location shows the proper values here but when I access it from MainActivity it shows null value.

Comment: [That's how mulithreading works...](http://ideone.com/PPHi95) If I had a penny for every time similar question were asked ...

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` run simultaneously with main thread so when you call `execute();`

method immediately control goes to next line :

```
   String location = retrieve.sales_location;
```

put your code for location in `onPostExecute(Result result)` method

```
onPostExecute(Result result){
    String location = retrieve.sales_location;
    System.out.println("Location is: " + location);
}
```